# C# Google OAuth2 null Refresh Tokens: How to start fresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am running tests on a site I built and trying to get a refresh token to store as a claim but it always returns null.  Please note that it DID work before, but it only worked the first time in each browser (Chrome, then Firefox, then Internet Explorer).

AccessType IS set to "offline" in all tests. Nowhere can I specify approval_prompt/ApprovalPrompt to "force" and anyway the documentation says to set AccessType to "offline" to get a refresh token (which is what I am doing).

I suspect the successive null refresh tokens have something to do with data stored somewhere in the SQLServer database that I can't find, and that I need to delete.  It could also be my inability to set ApprovalPrompt/approval_prompt to "force" within the C# code.

Scenario:

1. When I create a new user on the site in Chrome, registration works and a refresh token is provided.  To doublecheck, I delete the user and user claims and try it again in Chrome, but this time no refresh token is given on the registration attempt with the same email address.

   Tables user/claim data is deleted from are:

   aspnet_Applications

   aspnet_Membership

   aspnet_Users

   aspnet_UsersInRoles

   aspnet_Profiles

   [AspNetUserClaims]

   [AspNetUserLogins]

   [AspNetUsers]
2. Puzzled, so I try it in Firefox.  I register a new user (same email address) and a refresh token is provided on the first attempt.   To doublecheck, I delete the user and user claims and try it again in Firefox and this time no refresh token is given on the following registration attempt with the same email address.
3. I figure by now that it will only work once in browsers I haven't tried registering the account on yet.  So I try it again with Internet Explorer.  I register a new user (same email address) and a refresh token is provided on the first attempt.  But as last time, when I try to start fresh and delete all user data and claims it does not provide a refresh token on the following registration attempt with the same email address.

What gives?  Is it recognizing some older session? How can I get all the user data and claims fully deleted so that it will give me a refresh token as it worked the first time for every browser, OR force the approval prompt within this C# code?

Here is the code:

```
var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                AccessType = "offline",
                Caption = "Needs authentication from Google+ to proceed.",
                ClientId = "xxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxx",
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = context =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleAccessToken", context.AccessToken));

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.RefreshToken))
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleRefreshToken", context.RefreshToken));
                        }

                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleUserId", context.Id));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleUsername", context.Name));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleUserEmail", context.Email));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleTokenIssuedAt", DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString()));
                        var expiresInSec = (long)(context.ExpiresIn.Value.TotalSeconds);
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("GoogleTokenExpiresIn", expiresInSec.ToString()));

                        return Task.FromResult(true);
                    }
                },
            
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie
            };

            googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
            googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/consumersurveys");
        
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

I thought about clearing Chrome/Firefox/IE cache, but I shouldn't have to do that...Please share your thoughts on this and how you think I can reset users and their claims to start fresh.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.

1. Logged into Google and visited the app permissions page: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1
2. Once there, revoked access to the token for my email account.
3. When I ran my app again, it "forced" me to consent to access/permissions this time around and then also provided me with the refresh token!

Hope this helps anyone that has run into a similar issue.